# Could not export TimeSeries to CSV

Tags: export, time-series

I have tried the following code to export a `TimeSeries` to a CSV.

This is using code from a similar post "[Export TimeSeries[] to CSV or Excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126823/export-timeseries-to-csv-or-excel)".

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* Helper Functions to format the export *)
formatDate[date_DateObject]:=DateValue[date, {"Year", "Month", "Day"}]
formatTemperature[value_Quantity]:=QuantityMagnitude[value]

formatSeries[{date_DateOject,value_Quantity}]:={formatDate@date, formatTemperature@value} //Flatten
convertToList[timeSeries_TimeSeries]:=timeSeries["DatePath"] //Map@formatSeries

(* Get Weather Data *)
windSpeedSeries=WeatherData[{53.506574, -112.096163},"WindSpeed", {{2018,1,1},{2018,12,31}}]
temperatureSeries=WeatherData[{53.506574, -112.096163},"Temperature", {{2018,1,1},{2018,12,31}}]
```

When I call `convertToList[temperatureSeries]`, it appears that `convertToList` is not defined.

If I issue the following command:

```
temperatureSeries["DatePath"] // Map@formatSeries
```

I get the following output:

[[image: temperatureSeries["DatePath"] //Map@formatSeries output.[2]]

I think this is a basic question.

This looks like a series of commands that I would like to execute on each element in the list of {date, temperature} pairs.

How would I actually execute this so that I can successfully export the following data columns to a CSV file?

Year,
Month,
Day,
Temperature

If I simply call `Export["Temperatures.csv", temperatureSeries["DatePath"] //Map@formatSeries]`, I simply get a text version of the image above.

This leads me to believe that `formatSeries` in the code above is undefined. I am not clear on why `formatSeries` is undefined.

**Alternate Approach**

While this is not at all performant, the code below does work.  I would suggest that it be translated into a functional code equivalent.

```
temperatureSeries=WeatherData[{53.506574, -112.096163},"Temperature", {{2018,1,1},{2018,12,31}}]

temperatureList = Table[{temperatureSeries["DatePath"][[i]][[1]][[1]][[1]],
                         temperatureSeries["DatePath"][[i]][[1]][[1]][[2]],
                         temperatureSeries["DatePath"][[i]][[1]][[1]][[3]],
                         QuantityMagnitude[temperatureSeries["DatePath"][[i]][[2]]]},{i,1,Length[temperatureSeries["DatePath"]]}]

Export["Temperature.csv", temperatureList]
```

Comment: Notice that the `Head` of `temperatureSeries` as you defined it is `TemporalData`, not `TimeSeries`. Since you restricted the definition of `convertToList` to only working on `TimeSeries`, then yes it is technically undefined for the input you provided. I suspect that it will work if you fix or remove the pattern restrictions on your function definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well for me. You might want to try it.

```
data =
  Module[{dates, temps},
    dates = DateValue[#, {"Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"}] & /@ temperatureSeries["Dates"];
    temps = QuantityMagnitude[#] & /@ temperatureSeries["Values"];
    Flatten /@ Thread[{dates, temps}]];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "Temperature.csv"}], data]
```

The exported CSV file looks like this

> ```
> 2018,1,1,0,-26.3
> 2018,1,1,1,-27
> 2018,1,1,2,-27
> 2018,1,1,3,-26.7
> 2018,1,1,4,-27.2
> 2018,1,1,5,-27.2
> 2018,1,1,6,-27.4
> 2018,1,1,7,-27.9
> 2018,1,1,8,-28.5
> 2018,1,1,9,-28.2
> 2018,1,1,10,-28.2
> 2018,1,1,11,-28.6
>
>  ...
>
> 2018,1,31,12,-24.4
> 2018,1,31,13,-25.4
> 2018,1,31,14,-25.7
> 2018,1,31,15,-26.2
> 2018,1,31,16,-26
> 2018,1,31,17,-25.6
> 2018,1,31,18,-24.9
> 2018,1,31,19,-24.2
> 2018,1,31,20,-23.6
> 2018,1,31,21,-23.4
> 2018,1,31,22,-23.4
> 2018,1,31,23,-23.3
> ```

Notes:

- I only asked for the temperatures for January, 2018, in my query to `WeatherData`.
- Since the data in `temperatureSeries` is hourly, I added a hour column to the exported data. You can simply remove "Hour" from the 2nd `DateValue` argument if don't want this column.